# NVL using case in query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

We have a query that uses case in NVL statement
However I think NVL can be removed

Please refer to the part of the query below -

```
select f1, NVL((
        CASE
            WHEN PROD_CD = 'ESALE'
            THEN SUM (prod_count)
            WHEN PROD_CD = 'RSALE'
            THEN (SUM (prod_count) * -1)
            ELSE NULL
        END),0) AS SALEQTY
```

Can we also avoid NVL by writing like this

```
select f1, 
        CASE
            WHEN PROD_CD = 'ESALE'
            THEN SUM (prod_count)
            WHEN PROD_CD = 'RSALE'
            THEN (SUM (prod_count) * -1)
            ELSE 0
        END AS SALEQTY,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is an odd construct.  Second, I prefer `COALESCE()` (the standard function) to `NVL()` -- but that is irrelevant.

You need the `NVL()`/`COALESCE()` if all `prod_count` values can be `NULL` for a given group.  If that is the case, then you need the outer check.  Merely adding an `ELSE` on a different column doesn't help.

I'll also note that the logic looks suspicious.  Normally the `CASE` goes as the argument to `SUM()` -- and a `NULL`-check is usually not necessary:

```
SELECT f1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PROD_CD = 'ESALE'
                THEN prod_count
                WHEN PROD_CD = 'RSALE'
                THEN - prod_count
                ELSE 0
            END) AS SALEQTY,
```

Answer (score 1):

NVL check the first argument, and if that argument is null, then it replaces it with the second argument.
So yes, you absolutely can remove it, I have no idea who the hell did this as its completely pointless.

Maybe if the NVL was first and someone added the case statement later and didnt want to mess with the current code. Since I dont think there is really a difference in performance, it doesent hurt if it stays, it also doesent make it much more difficult to understand, so it can stay, but there is no reason for it to stay.